# how to obtain the IP addresses of nodes for mining pools?

Tags: mining-pools, full-node, miner-configuration, peer-discovery

I have set up a node for mining, and in order to maintain network stability and quickly receive the latest tasks, I would like to connect to nodes of some large mining pools. Does anyone know how to obtain the IP addresses of nodes for these large mining pools?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to obtain these IP addresses (that I know of) other than to contact the mining pool or to follow the sign up process for that mining pool. You don't need to know the IP addresses of multiple mining pools as your mining pool will take care of broadcasting any mined block that your hardware finds and probably has its own infrastructure for receiving mined blocks from other mining pools. If you are concerned with stability of the network of full nodes then just connect to multiple other full nodes (perhaps randomly), they don't need to be mining pools' full nodes.

If I misunderstood the question and you don't want to use a mining pool and solo mine instead then good luck in 2024. It is very rare for a solo miner to find a block (see this Coin Telegraph [article](https://cointelegraph.com/news/solo-bitcoin-miner-defies-odds-to-mine-valid-btc-block-gets-150k-block-reward)).

Comment: I noticed there is an evaluation of all nodes on https://bitnodes.io. If I were to set up a mining pool, can its nodes be referred to using bitnodes for connection? Do you know about the connection strategy?

Comment: @youcaizhao: Bitnodes just indexes the IP addresses of reachable full nodes on the network, it doesn't present any information on mining pools. Obviously if you find an IP address of an mining pool you can look it up on Bitnodes and share the Bitnodes URL for it.